# OpenCV Datamatrix Code Finder

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, zxing

Has anyone ever written or heard of a datamatrix code decoder written in OpenCV?

I have used the decoder that comes with [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), but to be honest, its pretty bad.  It needs to be a fully clear image, using the entire image, and **not at an angle**.  The latter being the biggest drawback for me.  There are many apps out there that can read an image and recover from things like *being blury, at an angle, or even only 40% of the image*.

If anyone knows another SDK that would work better, please let me know.  Ive used opencv many times, and it seems like it wouldn't be very hard to write a datamatrix decoder, I'm just surprised the code isnt out there.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually embedded. Furthermore, if you state 'it wouldnt be too hard', and given the fact that you are looking for it and haven't found it, how about contribute yourselves?
https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/datamatrix.cpp

Comment: I've tried this, it didn't work for me.  I ended up just dealing with the issues with ZXing.  Knowing what I do now, I probably could write my own.  At the time (4 months ago), I would not have know where to start